# TIMESTAMPZ формат при конвертации из Postgresql посредством JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, timestamp

Не могу найти информации на просторах интернета о том, какой использовать класс при маппинге объектов во время работы с JDBC. В базе данных postgreSql имеются колонки с типом TIMESTAMPZ или "Timestamp with time zone". При маппинге таких колонок с помощью LocalDateTime и ZonedDateTime Выдает ошибку:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: conversion to class java.time.ZonedDateTime from timestamptz not supported

Какой использовать класс для меппинга в такой ситуации вместо LocalDateTime или ZonedDateTime?

Comment: Попробуйте OffsetDateTime

Answer (score 4):

До появления Java Date/Time API для маппинга типа `TIMESTAMPTZ` использовался тип `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Начиная с версии JDBC 4.2 были [добавлены маппинги](https://tada.github.io/pljava/use/datetime.html) на соответствующие классы Java Date/Time:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| PostgreSQL type             | Pass to getObject/readObject |
------------------------------+-------------------------------
| date                        | java.time.LocalDate          |   
| time without time zone      | java.time.LocalTime          |
| time with time zone         | java.time.OffsetTime         |
| timestamp without time zone | java.time.LocalDateTime      |
| timestamp with time zone    | java.time.OffsetDateTime     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

История с поддержкой `JSR-310` и `JDBC 4.2` в СУБД и драйверах такова, что на самом деле творится что-то непонятное и это непонятное постоянно причиняет уйму боли.

**I**. "Официальное" название типа данных "timestamp with time zone" в СУБД на самом деле не отражает действительность, на самом деле именно ***часовой пояс*** СУБД в соответствующих полях не хранят, причина этому довольно прозаична: чтобы уметь быстро сравнивать даты со временем нужно уметь их быстро преобразовывать из одного часового пояса в другой, в то же время часовым поясам свойственно меняться: какие-то разделяются, какие-то, наоборот схлопываются, где-то вводят переход на летнее время, где-то наоборот отменяют, поэтому СУБД используют два типичных подхода для хранения "timestamp with time zone":

- всегда хранить в UTC (PostgreSQL, Oracle)
- хранить информацию о смещении (! речь не про часовой пояс, а про смещение) относительно UTC (MSSQL)

**II**. какой тип данных для "дат со временем" использовать в СУБД, это в большинстве случаев выбор разработчика, однако, здесь следует понимать, что универсального решения не существует, например с хранением "дат со временем" приведенных к UTC существует некоторая проблема, связанная с тем, что будущее не определено и если в данный момент времени мы в считаем, что полночь '1 января 2024 по Москве' соответствует '9 вечера 31 декабря 2023 по UTC', то завтра или через полгода это уже может быть совсем не так, т.е. если мы решили хранить в БД "даты со временем" используя тип "timestamp with time zone", то нужно быть готовым к тому, что рано или поздно нам придется данные в СУБД перебивать. Здесь в изначальном вопросе имеет место быть определенная странность: "имеются колонки с типом TIMESTAMPZ" - на мой взгляд, СУБД где одновременно используются типы "timestamp without time zone" и "timestamp with time zone" без дополнительных конвенций по наименованию - это не база данных, а помойка: нужно или везде иметь одинаковые типы данных, или каким-то образом помечать особенности хранения данных посредством наименования полей, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз лезть в структуру БД для понимания правильно ли я работаю с данными.

**III**. Какой именно тип использовать в жаве - на самом деле вопрос филосовский и очень много зависит от используемого фреймворка, например, хибернейт поддерживает работу и с `Instant`, и с `ZonedDateTime`, и с `LocalDateTime` вне зависимости от того что написано в спецификации `JDBC 4.2` - у разработчиков соответствующего фреймворка так или иначе существует цель привлечь как можно больше пользователей. Если же дело касается "чистого" JDBC, то тут единственный вариант - вдумчиво читать спецификацию, оценивать последствия и принимать решения, например, [ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1514092/550981) уже упомянули, что для `timestamptz` в `PostgreSQL` нужно либо использовать "современный" `OffsetDateTime` либо устаревшие типы `Timestamp`, `Date`, `Calendar` (здесь на самом деле разработчики драйвера `PostgreSQL` подложили свинью: для старых типов `Java` все работает вполне "ожидаемо", а в случае "современных" типов грабли разложены весьма предусмотрительно, в других СУБД все совсем иначе, аналогично только в `PostgreSQL` нельзя тип БД `date` в `LocalDateTime`)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.